# Python: inverse of len(set) is null

Tags: python-2.6

I have a non null set, let' say `myset`. I am trying to get the inverse of its length this way `1/len(myset)` and I am getting `0` although the length of the set is not that large so its inverse is null; `len(myset)` is in the order of 50.

Does anyone knows how to eccounter this?

Many thanks!

EDIT/UPDATE:

The code is very long, but here is the portion where I am using it:

```
from random import randint,random,uniform
import os
import math
import cplex
from datetime import datetime
from scipy.stats import norm

class Solving:
def __init__(self, init):
    self.init = init        
    return

def run(self):      

    model=cplex.Cplex()

    for i in self.init.getGreenNodes() - self.init.getRedNodes():
        for j in self.init.getDiscretValuesNb():
            model.variables.add(names=["X"+str((i,j))])
            model.variables.set_types("X"+str((i,j)),"B")

    model.variables.add(names=["Da"+str(i)])
        model.variables.set_types("Da"+str(i),"C")

    model.objective.set_sense(model.objective.sense.minimize)
    model.objective.set_linear("TCost",1)

    for i in self.init.getGreenNodes() - self.init.getRedNodes():
        aa=1/len(self.init.getGreenNodes() - self.init.getRedNodes())
        print aa
        model.linear_constraints.set_coefficients("Cstr1", "Da"+str((i)), aa)
```

This code is perfecly working when using python 3.5

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a full code sample that shows the problem.

Comment: @Marein: I have updated the code with code portion (The hall script is very long and can't t post it here).

Comment: You don't need to post the whole script, but please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop performing integer division.

```
1. / foo
```

Comment: that's it! Is it related to all versions 2 of Python or only 2.6?! Thanks!

Comment: `int / int` will result in a `int` in 2.x if `division` hasn't been imported from `__future__`. In 3.x it will result in a `float`.